# Diagramming tool with good connector auto-arrangement when I drag connected boxes

Tags: windows, gratis, diagram, drag-drop

I have been using Microsoft Visio. However, when I draw a bunch of boxes, connect them, then drag to rearrange the boxes, the rearrangement of the connectors is non-optimized and ugly.

Is there a gratis Windows app with good, intelligent, optimized and pleasing to the eye auto-rearrangement of connectors?

I don;t need much by way of features. It's just boxes with text in them, and connectors. All else is a welcome bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check https://draw.io It offer a lot of flexibility and it is quite "intelligent". Beside web version there is standalone one via menu Help->Get Desktop... [here](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/tag/v15.4.0).

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. I will give it a test & get back to you.

Comment: I am going to award this the answer. At first glance, I prefer it to Visio (for which I paid for a license, and this is free), and also to the free Yed. Since they have been developing it since 2005, I expect it to be very full featured. Thanks

Comment: At second glance, I regret having bought that Vision license. The conenctor handling with your answer is far superior to Visio.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely give [EdrawMax](https://www.edrawsoft.com/) a shot. It's not free, but it's definitely worth the price.